# Says Jasmine spy is not being called, but I can see that its being called

Tags: jasmine, es6-modules, jasmine2.0

I can't figure out why Jasmine is claiming that the function I'm spying on isn't being called, especially since it is logging in buildLinksObj when called through and not calling when I remove .and.callThrough() I feel like I've written similar code a bunch of times before without any problem. I'm using Jasmine 2.9

The error message I'm getting is:

```
1) addToLinks should call buildLinksObj if its given an object with children 
     it should add the personalized links to PageApp.meta.analytics.links
     Expected spy buildLinksObj to have been called.
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877webpack:///tests/specs/common/FetchPersonalContent.spec.js:854:0 <- tests/app-mcom.js:104553:48)
```

Here's the except of my code:

FetchPersonalContent.js

```
const buildLinksObj = (responseObj = {}, targetObj, PageApp) => {
  console.log('it logs in buildLinksObj') // This is logging!
}

const addToLinks = (responseArr, personalizedLinks) => {
  responseArr.forEach((media) => {
    const type = media.type;
      const typeObj = media[type];
      buildLinksObj(typeObj, personalizedLinks, PageApp);
      if (typeObj && typeObj.children) {
        console.log('has children!')
        console.log('typeObj.children is: ', typeObj.children);
        typeObj.children.forEach((child) => {
          console.log('has a child')
          buildLinksObj(child, personalizedLinks, PageApp);
          console.log('buildLinksObj was definitely called. what the heck?')
        });
      }
    });
}

export {buildLinksObj, addToLinks, FetchPersonalContent as default,
};
```

FetchPersonalContent.spec.js

```
import * as FetchPersonalContent from '../../../src/FetchPersonalContent'; // my path is definitely correct

describe('it should add the personalized links to PageApp.meta.analytics.links', () => {
  it('addToLinks should call buildLinksObj if its given an object with children ', () => {
    spyOn(FetchPersonalContent, 'buildLinksObj').and.callThrough();
    FetchPersonalContent.addToLinks([{
    "personalId": 30718,
    "type": "carousel",
    "carousel": {}
  }], {});
    expect(FetchPersonalContent.buildLinksObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: So, what you are asking is why if you remove `.and.callThrough();` it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling `FetchPersonalContent.buildLinksObj` in the spec file is not pointing to the same instance as `buildLinksObj` in the FetchPersonalContent.js file.

Why is `export {FetchPersonalContent as default}` required? I am assuming you have shared the complete content of FetchPersonalContent.js in your question.

**Possible solutions:**

You can try removing `FetchPersonalContent` from the `export` statement.

**Or**

Instead of

```
export {buildLinksObj, addToLinks, FetchPersonalContent as default,
};
```

You can directly `export` the constants in `FetchPersonalContent.js` file.